# Better phrases to describe "taking A-levels" or any other course

Tags: phrase-requests, formality

What phrase should I use when writing about my qualifications? I feel like saying e.g. "I am taking A-levels" sounds informal (A-levels is the examination students in England take). What other verb or phrase instead of "take" should I use?

Comment: *Take* is the verb used for tests- it's not informal; it just *is*   Unless you're in England where they *sit* exams.

Comment: I was going to suggest "matriculate" in the sense of "Pass the final school-leaving examination", but according to the OED that meaning is South African (http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/matriculate?q=Matriculate ) . That's wrong - it's used in Australia in that sense as well - but it does suggest that it's not widely used that way in Britain. (I doubt that Oxford would be wrong about that, especially as the CED (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/matriculate) doesn't list it in that sense either.)

Comment: The verb *matriculate* means to enter a name in the register of a university. It is also applied to a school-leaving examination, upon which university entry is dependent. The term was widely used in Britain in the first half of the 20th century but has largely fallen into disuse perhaps because the GCSE and A Level examinations are not directly set by universities and because UK universities operate a centralised admissions system. The universities mainly rely on the grades awarded in these public examinations. Oxford and Cambridge do set their own exams which some entrants take.

Comment: @Richard Smith could you explain what you mean by saying *"writing about my experience"*?

Comment: @Jim *Take* is more often used than *sit* in the UK nowadays.

Comment: It seems to me there are two questions there!

Comment: @Afsane - I basically meant describing my qualifications, sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: @RichardSmith You really need to edit your question because there are still some things unclear to me. For example I don't know if you are looking for an American version or it doesn't matter because as you referred in your question *"A-levels is the examination students in England take"*, so what?  By the way, please consider a proper tag if you mean it in American English.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to say that you're in the process of studying the course material in order to pass the course, I think that *taking* is fine. One take's a course; that's the verb that is used.

The Free Dictionary corroborates this:

> **take a course** [in something]: to enroll in a course and do the required work.

If you mean to say that you're presently in the process of examinations, you could say *I'm **sitting** my A-levels at the moment*.

There's an example in the Cambridge Dictionary:

> **sit** [EXAM]: to take an ​exam - *After I've sat my ​exams, I'm going on ​holiday.*

Answer (score 2):

***I am taking my A Levels*** is a perfectly idiomatic, well-understood, and commonly-used form, in Britain. e.g. *I shall be taking my A Levels in June*.